# How to remove whitespace from a file in c

Tags: c, io

I want the file to be without any whitespaces but the code I have tried below  I am not sure how do I delete a char so I tried inserting a backspace(non-printable character) but this doesn't seem to work

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
 FILE* fp;
 fp = fopen("in.txt","r+");
 int ch;
 while((ch = getc(fp))!=EOF){
     if( (ch == ' ') || (ch == '\n')){
         fputc(8,fp);
       }

   }
}
```

The file is

```
abcd efgh
```

Is there any working way to do this?, without using a new file (ie.copy all except whitespace)

Comment: Writing a backspace character `'\b'` to a file puts out a byte (usually the value is 8 — but you should use `'\b'`), and advances the file position by one (just the same as outputting any other character does).  If you want to move backwards, you have to use `fseek()`.  Note that in update mode, you must use `fseek()` or another positioning operation between each read and write operation, and also between each write and read operation.  Anything else is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete a character from the middle of a file.

What you need to do is create a new file, and write all the characters that *aren't* whitespace to the new file. You can then delete the old file if you want.

Comment: Why nothing happens when I pass a backspace char(ASCII 8) in putc()?

Comment: @FenilSuchak Does it not even write a backspace character to the file? In that case it's possibly because you didn't call fseek between reading and writing and reading, or because you didn't close the file.